# Bind and Unbind directives dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an Administrative Backend and have been running into an issue. The problem is that I need to dynamically bind and unbind certain directives within my application but I have not found a viable way of doing this through my research.

For example, I am using the ui-router module. Say I would like to dynamically add another view: `<div ui-view="view2"></div>` and have this view be instantly populated and accessible by angular while removing the attribute should keep the view but unbind any future changes to that view.

Is this something that is possible using angular?

Comment: If it is AngularJS, then you can try to wrap the scope watchers inside a function which can be enabled/disabled like this one https://gist.github.com/mariussoutier/5921001 . Then disable when needed.
I did something similar for our app when there are so many watchers which causing some performance issue.
Should be harder with Angular as change detection happens automatically so will need to do something different if performance is your concern. If you want to disable functionalities then it's a different scenario.

Comment: Hope this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525655/how-to-dynamically-bind-a-directive-in-angularjs